# Triple lines in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to be able to draw tripled paths in TikZ. I guess this could be done by some clever style which draws a big doubled path to get the outer curves correct, then uses some clever post-action hackery to draw a second non-doubled path to produce the central curve. I need to be able to set the thickness and the spacings of the three lines independently, just like one can with doubled lines.

*Luckily*, I don't need arrowheads on the line!

Anyone up to the challenge? :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the idea is that the three lines will be evenly spaced. So there are two parameters I want to be able to supply: the width of the individual curves, and the separation between adjacent curves.

Comment: And by using the term "path", you mean that this is not just a straight line, but a number of connected line segments, possibly with rounded edges/curves at each connection. And, no `pstricks`?

Comment: Hi Werner. I need to end up with a PDF - does that rule out pstricks? Maybe that's a stupid question. I'm not sure what the pros and cons are of that option. But anyway, yes, it's a fully-general path. I'll need to use the `\draw [triple] (A) to [out=45,in=100] (B)` construction and its ilk.

Comment: `pstricks` can also be used to produce PDF output via a different compiling sequence or [`pst-pdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-pdf).

Comment: The arrowheads would have been what made this *interesting* ... (actually, I do have a solution for that; just waiting for someone to ask the right question)

Comment: One day, Andrew!

Comment: @LoopSpace maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230098) one?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Did you not notice the date on this one?  The likelihood of me being able to remember what on earth I was thinking back then is almost surely zero.  I have 900 tex files in my scratch directory and I'm not looking through them all to find the one with the solution in it.

Comment: @LoopSpace oh, no, I didn't. But well, maybe you have fun solving that anyway. But my poor approach already got accepted; so, never mind.

Comment: Using the preaction approach as in zeroth's answer, it is easy to deal with arrowhead, too. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504561/25158).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So basically a pre action on the path.
I have added a style which is shown how to be called, notice that it will always `draw`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    triple/.style args={[#1] in [#2] in [#3]}{
        draw,#1,preaction={draw,#2,preaction={draw,#3}}
    }
}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[triple={[line width=1mm,red] in
      [line width=2mm,blue] in
      [line width=4mm,black]}] (0,0) to[out=10,in=100] (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should wait for more answers, but that seems to do the job! Thanks!

Comment: @JamieVicary, yes that should at least attract other users who might drop in on a solution.

Comment: I adapted your code to produce this, which works very well for my purposes:

Comment: \newlength\triplesep
\newlength\triplelinewidth
\setlength\triplesep{1pt}
\setlength\triplelinewidth{1pt}
\tikzset{triple/.style={line width=\triplelinewidth,black,
    preaction={
        preaction={draw,line width=2\triplesep+3\triplelinewidth,black},
        draw,line width=2\triplesep+\triplelinewidth,white}
    }
}

Comment: Oops, wasn't expecting it to look like that ... anyway, maybe it'll be useful for someone :).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \rput(2.5,4){Step 1}
    \psline[linewidth=5pt](5,5)
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \rput(2.5,4){Step 2}
    \psline[border=1pt,bordercolor=yellow,linewidth=1pt](5,5)
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \rput(2.5,4){Step 3}
    \psline[linewidth=5pt](5,5)
    \psline[border=1pt,bordercolor=yellow,linewidth=1pt](5,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: which parameter setting do you use for the gif. I tried: `convert -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 150 -alpha off <file>.pdf <file>.gif` but the output is lousy ...

Comment: `convert: UnrecognizedAlphaChannelType remove' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/657.` I have ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2012-04-26 Q16.