# Want to Draw basic geometric figures in Latex

Tags: diagrams

I have been learning latex for few month. In-fact beginners in latex.
I want to draw some geometry figures for (examples given below) in latex.
I came to know that it is possible by Tikz , pstricks and asymptote but still i am not aware about to use these. Even my question is, is there any books or printed material available? or any other source to learn these so i can improve my latex knowledge for graphics. Please help me.[image]   Please provide me codes for given images.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are nearly 12000 questions on this site [tagged with `tikz-pgf`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), so that is one source of information. More learning material on TikZ is listed in [Materials for learning TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779)

Comment: An example question: [Marking angles in a parallelogram congruent using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253007)

Comment: No need to down vote this; our site is filled with these type of questions and a lot of people have built their reputation on such questions

Comment: You can take a look at the `pst-eucl` package (from the `pstricks` family).