# Tikz draw lines on Triangle

Tags: tikz-styles

I was wondering if any of you know how to draw the lines there is in this picture? I don't have any problems with drawing the triangles and angels itself, it is just the lines there are going through the angle?
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-2cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (2.2cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {c} (B) -- node[sloped,above] {a} (C) -- node[below] {b} (A);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Paul i have updated the Question with the code

Comment: See if [Marking angles in a parallelogram congruent using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253007) is helpful.

Comment: it does indeed! but i am not sure wich part of the code i need to insert in mine

Comment: It's the part after the comment "%Opposite sides of the parallelogram are marked to indicate that they are congruent."  The syntax used is explained in the pgfmanual in the section about coordinate calculations (library calc, Chapter 13.5 in my version).